# Add an up button to the Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

Is it possible to add a button to the Finder that goes up a directory? I looked at the buttons available under customize and didn't see one, but thought there might be a hack out there.

Comment: Are you saying you want a single step up button, instead of having to click twice on that icon (once to open it, once to pick the parent) just to go up a single directory?

Comment: @VxJasonxV yep, exactly. I know, I'm lazy, and I'm not a big fan of keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @SWrobel If you're lazy then you'd best learn to use the mouse less, and keyboard shortcuts more. +1 VxJasonxV's answer

Comment: @macaco I understand some people love keyboard shortcuts, but when I'm already navigating with my mouse, which is what I prefer for browsing folders, it's easier not to switch back to the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current solution I'm using is [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) which lets you add an up button as well as do many of the things that PathFinder or TotalFinder let you do (like sort folders to the top) but for free.

[image: XtraFinder Up Button]

Comment: Looks awesome, but how can I add the up-button using XtraFinder? (I'm new to mac and using OS X 10.9.5). Thanks

Comment: @lcv install XtraFinder, go to Finder menu > XtraFinder > Preferences, go to the Features tab and look for "Show Go Up button in the toolbar" (it's about 4th from the bottom)

Comment: awww this doesnt work in 10.12 =( too bad.

Answer (score 20):

Would you be willing to just use a keyboard shortcut instead?

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>↑ Up</kbd>

Voilà.

Comment: Is that Lion specific? Or can I do that in SL?

Comment: I believe it's been that way for many many OS X versions, I don't have a Snow Leopard install to test on.

Comment: That Command-Up Arrow shortcut has been around for ages. Even before OS X, I believe...

Answer (score 18):

Choose View > Show Path Bar to show the Path bar at the bottom of Finder windows.

Then, to go up one level, just double-click on the second-to-last item in the hierarchy. For example, I'd double-click on `mdouma46` in the image below to go up one level.

[image]

Comment: great solution to avoid fiddling with scripts

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be to save a script like this as an application in AppleScript Editor and drag it to the toolbar.

```
try
    tell app "Finder" to tell window 1 to set target to container of target
end try
```

Comment: Just for those who do not know [how to save AppleScript as .app](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/01/13/applescript-saving-scripts/). Also, note that this came very handy for creating a "button" for opening new [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com) tabs in the current directory, from within Finder, based on [this](https://github.com/pablito56/devel_scripts/blob/master/iterm2/new_tab.sh). Another solution using services is [here](http://peterdowns.com/posts/open-iterm-finder-service.html).

Answer (score 7):

I found this app that does what I was looking for. Once extracting it to your Applications folder or wherever you want to keep it, drag it to the Finder next to the Back/Forward buttons. It's a little bit smaller than them in Lion, but the styling fits.

[Click here to download](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/3M2p3H2q3C35132o0b0R/Finder_Up-Button_v1.0.dmg)

Credit to Simon Slangen for creating the app

[image: Image of up button]

Comment: this worked in ealier version of OSX, but is sadly not working in 10.12. I would love to find some alternatives like this. Its unbelievable how terrible navigation is in OSX still. A simple up button isnt rocket science.

Answer (score 5):

When you Command-Click on the folder icon on an item in the title bar of a Finder window, you get a contextual menu showing the folder hierarchy to the root of the drive. You can then use the mouse to select a higher level of the hierarchy and move there in the Finder window. It's convenient and appealing because you see the whole hierarchy.

[image: before command-click]

[image: after command-click]

Comment: That function is identical to the button listed in the OPs question, but it harder to invoke.

Comment: Valid point. Yet it gave me the opportunity to add some screen shots.

Comment: Furthermore, the "Command-Click" on the icon also works with document windows in many Mac OS X applications. So if you have a document open in Preview, and you want to see its folder path, you can use the same method from within Preview.

Comment: More bonus: This also works with the URL in Safari. It provides access to every path down to the server.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a simple Automator app to do this and put it's icon in the tool bar. It may be slightly slower than an AppleScript app, but the Automator app won't change the focus of the window when it launches (the current Finder window remains the active window the whole time), so it has a more integrated feel.

Still, the quickest way is definitely to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>.

In Automator, add a "Run Applescript" action and replace the entire default script with this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell application "System Events" to key code 126 using command down
end tell
```

This script simply sends <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to the Finder.

Save your Automator app, then drag its icon to the Finder's tool bar. You may want to first make a new icon for it to indicate its function.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I made an App for up button.

http://autometa.ro/apps/up_button.html

It is free.

thx.

Comment: Hm, thanks, but this isn't working on my Machine (US keyboad layout, 10.8.3). Sometimes when I click the button it moves the selection up one place (same as pressing the up arrow on the keyboard) but it never goes up a directory. It's as if it's sending Up but not Command+Up.

Comment: "This site can’t be reached"